# Isomorphism between factor group and cyclic group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Is $\mathbb{Z_4}\times\mathbb{Z_6}/\langle(0,1)\rangle$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_6}$? 
I have counted the order of the former is 4 whereas the order of latter is 6 . Is this the reason that I can conclude they are not isomorphic?

Comment: Of course that's an excellent reason: they don't have the same cardinal, which is a rather trivial consequence (i.e., a necessary condition) of being isomorphic...whic is, among other things, a $\;1-1\;$ map !

Comment: So his two is isomorphic right ? Then how about $\mathbb{Z_6}\times\mathbb{Z_4}/\langle(0,1)\rangle$, are they isomorphic?

Comment: Deleted my answer because @DonAntonio's is more than sufficient.

Comment: See also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2256167/whats-the-meaning-of-factors-collapsing-in-quotients-like-mathbbz-4-times?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 1):

If $\;A\cong B\;$ , then there exists a **bijective** function $\;f:A\to B\implies |A|=|B|\;$ (cardinal = number of elements, if the sets are finite) are the same